# Undefined/blank values in ajax call to XML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I am making an ajax call to an xml list to get the "SOFTWARE" values in the xml list when the department and groups match the html inputs and xml tags. For each piece of software I am trying to get it to display a checkbox with the text of software next to it. It creates the checkboxes, but no text is grabbed. I either get blanks, 'undefined', or [Object Object].

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here or how I should go about it?

```
function findTechPersona() {
$("#techpersonaList").empty();

  $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "bleh.com",
contentType: "charset=utf-8",
dataType: "xml",
async: true,
success: parsePersonaXML
});

function parsePersonaXML(xml) {

$(xml).find("DEPTId").each(function() {
var htmlDepartment = $("#Department").val();
var htmlGroup = $("#techpersonaGroup").val();
var xmlGroup = $(this).find("GROUP_DESCRIPTION").text();
var xmlDepartment = $(this).find("DESCRIPTION").text();
var xmlSoftwares = $(this).find("SOFTWARE");

if (htmlDepartment == xmlDepartment && htmlGroup == xmlGroup)
  $(this).find("SOFTWARE").each(function() {
    var sd= $(this).find("SOFTWARE").text();
    $("#techpersonaList").append('<input type="checkbox" checked /> ' + sd + '<br />');
  });
});
}
}
```

The xml structure is set up like this:

```
<DEPTId id = "1234">
 <GROUP_DESCRIPTION>Something</GROUP_DESCRIPTION>
 <DESCIPTION>Some department</DESCRIPTION>
 <SOFTWARE>piece 1<SOFTWARE>
 <SOFTWARE>DSFAON</SOFTWARE>
 <SOFTWARE>asdvn</SOFTWARE>
<DEPTId>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of yours :

```
var sd= $(this).text();
```

Comment: Thank you! That got me exactly what I wanted! I can't believe it was just that...

Comment: Glad it helped :-

Comment: what if i had <SOFTWARE1>text</SOFTWARE1> <SOFTWARE2>TEXT2</SOFTWARE2> could I cycle through those tags using the same find method ex. $(this).find("SOFTWARE[x]").text();